# Какого рода междометие "ах"?

Tags: оформление-текста, междометие

> Мне важно было первой войти в зал, встретить его без ротозеев, – как
>   структуру, как конструкцию, – мне важно было сказать свой Ах!

"Ах" в кавычках со строчной?

*...мне важно было сказать свой (своё) "ах"!*

---

По прецеденту?

[фе, нескл., с. (высказать своё фе)](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%84%D0%B5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** Если я правильно поняла словарную статью Т. Ф. Ефремовой, то **ах** все-таки среднего рода.
[АХ](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%90%D1%85)
1. **ср.** Восклицание, вздох удивления, сожаления, печали.

**II.** Субстантивированные, то есть перешедшие в разряд имен существительных, наречия, междометия и другие неизменяемые части речи относятся к среднему роду.
Например: *Далече **грянуло ура*** (А. С. Пушкин).

[Грамматический род субстантивированных слов и аббревиатур](https://studfiles.net/preview/5786976/page:11/)

*Надежда вскипела в ней сотнями воздушных пузырьков и выплеснулась наружу бурным всплеском, похожим на **протяжное “ах!”*** (Р. Буревой. Колдун из Темногорска).

*...чувствовалось, что все с лихорадочным нетерпением ждут следующего выступления. И **протяжное "ах"** вырвалось разом из каждой груди* (Мале Лео. Смерть ростовщика).

*Все вздрагивают и пугливо оглядываются. У мамы вырывается **испуганное "ах!"*** (С. В. Ковалевская. Мемуары).

**III.** Я бы написала так (средний род; со строчной; в кавычках; восклицательный знак внутри кавычек): *...мне важно было сказать **своё "ах!".***

Comment: Все примеры - на случай цитаты (с кавычками). Условное существительное _ура_ (восклицание) - действительно, среднего рода. Ахи и охи - вероятнее всего, разновидность "вздохов" (вдохов и выдохов соотв.) :) . "Ахаль" в той статье - и вовсе вариант _женского_ рода в род. падеже мн. числа.

Comment: Извините, не понимаю Вас. 1. _Ахи и охи - вероятнее всего, разновидность "вздохов" (вдохов и выдохов соотв.) :)._ Я не вижу ни в вопросе, ни в моем ответе никаких "ахов-охов". 2. _**"Ахаль"** в той статье..._ — в какой статье?

Comment: В словарной статье Даля по вашей первой ссылке.

Comment: Ещё раз извините, но я ссылаюсь на Ефремову (первый пункт). В. И. Даля _нигде_ не упоминаю.

Answer (score 2):

Мне важно было первой войти в зал, встретить его без ротозеев, – как структуру, как конструкцию, – мне важно было сказать свое "ах"!

Где-то вдали послышалось протяжное «ох». –

Все междометия являются неизменяемыми частями речи. По поводу кавычек. При таком употреблении междометия обычно заключаются в кавычки и пишутся со строчной. Хотя встречаются примеры и без кавычек.

**Ср.: Атакующие кричали "ура". Над полем боя гремело "ура". // Клич воинов, выражающий одобрение чего-л., восторг по поводу чего-л. Войска крикнули "ура" генералу, принимающему парад.**

**Где-то вдали послышалось протяжное «ох». –**

Answer (score 2):

Об изменяемости и родах междометий. Широко применяется выражение "ахи и охи" (можно найти у Тургенева, Салтыкова-Щедрина и у многих простых литераторов), с сокращением до одних только "ахов" или "охов". В нём междометия (во множ. числе) явно изменяются по падежам подобно существительным, пишутся без кавычек и со строчной буквы. Единственное, чего из этого не видно, это род, но если уж они трактуются как существительные, то по окончанию ед. числа род, скорее всего, *мужской*.

Вариант с кавычками и средним родом (по неопределённому видовому наменованию "сказанное", прозвучавшее) можно рассматривать как запасной (обходной), но самоцитата не всегда подходит к контексту (здесь лирический герой не планировал буквально издать звук "ах") или к стилю (когда желателен одиночный "аховый" окказионализм). Без кавычек же (по аналогии с "ахами и охами") условному существительному приходится приписывать грамматический род.

> Когда он ахнул, его ах ещё долго отзывался многократным эхо, отражаясь от скал
>   каньона.

Comment: Alex-ander, именное устойчивое выражение ахи-охи  не является междометием  Поэтому рассматривать его как склоняемый вариант междометия ах или ох неправильно.

Comment: В любом таком выражении (в отличие от _цитат_ с реальным междометием) новым существительным только _подменяют_ междометие, это как бы его "местоимение". И обращаются с такой заменой как с _существительным_.

Comment: Обращаются как с существительным, потому что это и есть существительное. А не междометие. Междометие в любом контексте не склоняется.